# React Native Issue: undefined is not an object (evaluationg 'this.props.navigator.push')

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigator

Am a react native novice and am trying to navigate between screens ... I followed a simple tutorial and unfortunately, when I press the "To Stats Page" TouchableHighlight I get the error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator.push'). Attached are the screenshots of the home screen and the error (upon clicking TO STATS PAGE), and below is the code (I included a comment for where I believe the error occurs):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {AppRegistry,StyleSheet,TouchableHighlight,Navigator,Text,View} from 'react-native';

class Navi extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={{ name: 'main' }}
        renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
      />
    );
  }
  renderScene(route, navigator) {
     if(route.name == 'main') {
       return <Main navigator={navigator}  />
     }
     if(route.name == 'stats') {
       return <Stats navigator={navigator} />
     }
  }
}

export default class Main extends Component {
  // THINK THE ERROR IS HERE
  navigate(routeName) {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      name: routeName
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Main
        </Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.navigate.bind(this, "stats")}>
          <Text>TO STATS PAGE</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Stats extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Stats
        </Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>{this.props.navigator.pop()}}>
          <Text>BACK</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {marginTop:20,flex: 1,justifyContent: 'center',alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',},
  welcome: {fontSize: 20,textAlign: 'center',margin: 10,},
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('navi', () => Navi);
```

[Home Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R33bF.png)

[Error when touching to stats page, using expo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICM5t.png)

Answer (score -1):

Guys I figured it out am the best!!! The fix is Navi should be exported not main ...